# Java: Ways for source code autocompletion on netbeans having external source

Tags: java, netbeans, autocomplete, static-analysis

First of all, I'm not sure about if the title or the tags are correct. If not, someone please correct me

My question is if there are any tools or ways to create an autocomplete list with items from an external source, having netbeans parsing it and warn me if there are any errors.

-- **The problem**: I use JDBC and I want to model somehow all my schemas, tables and columns so that netbeans can parse it and warn me if I have anything wrong. For example with a normal use of JDBC I would had a function:

```
ResultSet execSelect( String cols, String table ){
     return statement.executeQuery("SELECT "+cols+" FROM "+table); }
```

The problem is that someone should know exactly what are the available params for that to pass the correct strings.

I would like netbeans to show me somehow an autocomplete list with all available options.

PS. I had exactly the same problem when I was building a web application and I wanted somehow to get all paths for my external resources like images, .js files, .css files etc.

-- **Thoughts so far**:
My thoughts till now were to put a .java file with public static final String vars with some how nested static classes so that I could access from anywhere. For example:

```
DatabaseModel.MySchema.TableName1.ColumnName2
```

would be a String varialble with the 'ColumnName2' column and 'TableName1' table. That would help me with autocompletes but the problem is that there is no type checking. In other words someone could use any string, global defined or not as a table and as a column which is not correct either. I'm thinking to use nested enums somehow to cover these cases about type checking but I'm not sure if that would be a good solution in any case.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came up with writting a "script" that connects to mysql gets all meta data (every column of every table of every schema) and creates a java file with predefined classes and Strings that describes the model. For example:
- If you want the name of the column C1 from table T1 from schema S1 you would type DatabaseModel.S1.T1.C1._ which is a public static final String with the column name.
- If you want the table T2 from schema S2 you would type DatabaseModel.S2.T2 which is a class that implements DatabaseTable interface. So the function: execSelect could take a DatabaseTable and a DatabaseColumn as a parameter.

Here is the code (not tested but the idea is clear I think).

```
public static void generateMysqlModel(String outputFile) throws IOException, SQLException{
    //** Gather the database model
    // Maps a schema -> table -> column
    HashMap<String,HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>> model = 
            new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>>();

    openDatabase();
    Connection sqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    DatabaseMetaData md = sqlConn.getMetaData();

    ResultSet schemas = md.getSchemas(); // Get schemas
    while( schemas.next() ){ // For every schema
        String schemaName = schemas.getString(1);
        model.put( schemaName, new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>() );
        ResultSet tables = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);  // Get tables
        while (tables.next()) { // For every table
            String tableName = tables.getString(3);
            model.get(schemaName).put( tableName, new ArrayList<String>() );
            // Get columns for table
            Statement s = sqlConn.createStatement();  // Get columns
            s.execute("show columns in "+tables.getString(3)+";");
            ResultSet columns = s.getResultSet();
            while( columns.next() ){ // For every column
                String columnName = columns.getString(1);
                model.get(schemaName).get(tableName).add( columnName );
            }
        }
    }

    closeDatabase();


    //** Create the java file from the collected model
    new File(outputFile).createNewFile();
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter(outputFile) ) ;

    bw.append( "public class DatabaseModel{\n" );
    bw.append( "\tpublic interface DatabaseSchema{};\n" );
    bw.append( "\tpublic interface DatabaseTable{};\n" );
    bw.append( "\tpublic interface DatabaseColumn{};\n\n" );
    for( String schema : model.keySet() ){
        HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> schemaTables = model.get(schema);
        bw.append( "\tpublic static final class "+schema+" implements DatabaseSchema{\n" );
        //bw.append( "\t\tpublic static final String _ = \""+schema+"\";\n" );
        for( String table : schemaTables.keySet() ){
            System.out.println(table);
            ArrayList<String> tableColumns = schemaTables.get(table);
            bw.append( "\t\tpublic static final class "+table+" implements DatabaseTable{\n" );
            //bw.append( "\t\t\tpublic static final String _ = \""+table+"\";\n" );
            for( String column : tableColumns ){
                System.out.println("\t"+column);
                bw.append( "\t\t\tpublic static final class "+column+" implements DatabaseColumn{"
                        + " public static final String _ = \""+column+"\";\n"
                        + "}\n" );
            }
            bw.append( "\t\t\tpublic static String val(){ return this.toString(); }" );
            bw.append( "\t\t}\n" );
        }
        bw.append( "\t\tpublic static String val(){ return this.toString(); }" );
        bw.append( "\t}\n" );
    }
    bw.append( "}\n" );

    bw.close();
}
```

PS. For the resources case in a web application I guess someone could get all files recursively from the "resources" folder and fill in the model variable. That will create a java file with the file paths. The interfaces in that case could be the file types or any other "file view" you want.

I also thought that it would be useful to create the .java file from an XML file for any case, so anyone would just create some kind of defintion in an xml file for that purpose.
If someone implements anything like that can post it here.

Any comments/improvements will be welcomed.